# How to include color in legend that does not occur in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to create a scatter plot which shows 2 different groups. For reasons, I want the legend of that plot to show 3 groups instead. Group 3 does not occur in the data, but it should still show up in the plot. I tried something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create a sample data frame
data <- data.frame(
  x = 1:4,
  y = 1:4,
  group = c("A", "B", "A", "B")
)

# Create the ggplot object with color aesthetics
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y, color = group)) +
  geom_point()  # Example geom, e.g., points

# Customize the legend
plot <- plot + scale_color_manual(
  values = c("red", "blue", "green"),  # Color values for each group A, B, and C
  labels = c("Group A", "Group B", "Group C"),  # Labels for each group
  breaks = c("A", "B", "C")  # Specify the breaks for the legend
)
```

However R is "smart" enough to notice that Group C is not used and drops it from the legend. Any idea how I can prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `drop = FALSE` to your `scale_color_manual` call:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y, color = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("red", "blue", "green"),  # Color values for each group A, B, and C
    labels = c("Group A", "Group B", "Group C"),  # Labels for each group
    breaks = c("A", "B", "C"),  # Specify the breaks for the legend
    drop = FALSE  # Prevent dropping unused factor levels from the legend
  )
```

[image: scatter plot]

Comment: Interesting, this code doesnt change anything for me... Can you tell me which version of ggplot you are using? I am using `3.4.0`

Comment: Ahh, in order to make your code work, I have to call `data$group <- factor(data$group, levels = c("A","B","C"))` first. I.e. "C" has to occur as a factor